# Image Sliding is not working in ViewBag foreach loop using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, bootstrapping

I am trying to show Images in a slideshow with text. But in my code all images show in line one after another. Looping is not working for slideshow.I am not getting the correct logic in my code how should I proceed to get all images in slide show.My View code is as follows-

```
 <div class="wrapper wrapper-content">


@foreach (var item in ViewBag.Cities)
    {
            foreach (var image in item.Images)
            {
                <div class="container-fluid bg-1 text-center">
                <h3>@item.Name</h3>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="inner">

                    </div>
                    <div class="ibox-content ">
                        <div class="carousel slide" id="carousel2">
                            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                                <li data-slide-to="0" data-target="#carousel2" class="active"></li>
                                <li data-slide-to="1" data-target="#carousel2"></li>
                                <li data-slide-to="2" data-target="#carousel2" class=""></li>
                            </ol>
                            <div class="carousel-inner">
                                <div class="item active">

                                    <img alt="image" class="img-responsive" src="@image" style="height:400px;width:500px">

                                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                                        <p>@item.Name</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                            </div>
                            <a data-slide="prev" href="#carousel2" class="left carousel-control">
                                <span class="icon-prev"></span>
                            </a>
                            <a data-slide="next" href="#carousel2" class="right carousel-control">
                                <span class="icon-next"></span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            }

            <div class="container-fluid bg-2 text-center">
                <h3>Description about @item.Name</h3>
                <p>@Html.Raw(@item.Shorttext)</p>
            </div>
            <div class="container-fluid bg-3 text-center">
                <h3>Geo Location</h3>
                <p>Longitude: @item.GeoCoordinates.Longitude and Latitude: @item.GeoCoordinates.Latitude </p>
                <h3> </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper wrapper-content">
            </div>

    }
</div>
```

I am giving my controller class code just for understanding -

```
public ActionResult PlaceInformation(City objCityModel)
    {

        string name = objCityModel.Name;
        ViewBag.Title = name;

        var ReadJson = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath(@"~/App_Data/POI_Json/" + name + ".json"));

        RootObject json = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<RootObject>(ReadJson);
        List<Poi> mycities = new List<Poi>();

        foreach (var item in json.poi)
        {
            Poi obj = new Poi()
            {
                Name = item.Name,
                Shorttext = item.Shorttext,
                GeoCoordinates = item.GeoCoordinates,
                Images = item.Images,

            };
            mycities.Add(obj);
        }

        ViewBag.Cities = mycities;

        return View();
    }
```

My Json file to get all data is look like this-

```
{
"poi": [
    {
        "Name": "Laboe Naval Memorial",
        "Shorttext": "The Laboe Naval Memorial is a memorial located in Laboe,",
        "GeoCoordinates": {
            "Longitude": 10.23079681,
            "Latitude": 54.41218567
        },
        "Images": [
            "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ec/Marineehrenmal_Laboe_1.jpg",
            "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/15/Marine_-_Ehrenmal_Laboe.jpg/300px-Marine_-_Ehrenmal_Laboe.jpg",
            "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/69/Ehrenmal_und_Uboot_Laboe.jpg",
            "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/38/Prinz_Eugen_Schraube_1.jpg"

        ]
    },
    {
        "Name": "Zoological Museum of Kiel University",
        "Shorttext": "The Zoological Museum of Kiel University is a zoological muse Karl.."
            "Longitude": 10.14416695,
            "Latitude": 54.32805634
        },
        "Images": [
            "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/da/Zoologisch-Voelkerkundl_Museum_Kiel_1.jpg/400px-Zoologisch-Voelkerkundl_Museum_Kiel_1.jpg"
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Based on the cshtml file, you are making THREE slideshows instead of one. Is that your intention?

Comment: Yes. It shows three Slideshow. But I need 3 Images in one slidshow

Comment: You need to move the `foreach` loop inside the div with class `carousel-inner`

Comment: @DPac Then it shows error

Comment: Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'image' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Yes That is why I am explaining. If i Move foreach loop to carousel inner it gives this error

Comment: It totally ruin my output

Comment: It shouldn't given an error. Your code should be like `<div class="carousel-inner">@foreach (var image in item.Images){<div class="item">.......</div>}</div>`

Comment: @DPac Now all images show in a line one by one and one slide only

Comment: Please do not use the bootstrapping tag. It's not twitter-bootstrap

Comment: @DanielCheung: Ok I am removing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner loop should be re-arranged. 
You need to loop the images and set the ul's and li's then again for the source. It should look like this:

```
<div class="wrapper wrapper-content">


@foreach (var item in ViewBag.Cities)
    {

                <div class="container-fluid bg-1 text-center">
                <h3>@item.Name</h3>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="inner">

                    </div>
                    <div class="ibox-content ">
                        <div class="carousel slide" id="carousel2">
                            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                              @{var i = -1;
                        foreach (var image in item.Images)
                        {

                        <li data-slide-to="@(++i)" data-target="#carousel2" class="@(i==0? "active":"")"></li>

                        }
                        }
                            </ol>
                            <div class="carousel-inner">
                             @{var isFirst = true;
                              foreach (var image in item.Images)
                              {
                                <div class="item @(isFirst ? "active": "")">
                                    @(isFirst = false)
                                    <img alt="image" class="img-responsive" src="@image" style="height:400px;width:500px">

                                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                                        <p>@item.Name</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                              }
                              }



                            </div>
                            <a data-slide="prev" href="#carousel2" class="left carousel-control">
                                <span class="icon-prev"></span>
                            </a>
                            <a data-slide="next" href="#carousel2" class="right carousel-control">
                                <span class="icon-next"></span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="container-fluid bg-2 text-center">
                <h3>Description about @item.Name</h3>
                <p>@Html.Raw(@item.Shorttext)</p>
            </div>
            <div class="container-fluid bg-3 text-center">
                <h3>Geo Location</h3>
                <p>Longitude: @item.GeoCoordinates.Longitude and Latitude: @item.GeoCoordinates.Latitude </p>
                <h3> </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper wrapper-content">
            </div>

               }
</div>
```

Comment: @Ziv_Weissman I am getting error in this line  var i = -1;
                                foreach (var image in item.Images)
                                {
                                
                                <li data-slide-to="(++i)" data-target="#carousel2" class="(i==0? "active":"")"></li>

                                } showing Error 1 The name 'i' does not exist in the current context

Comment: I've edited, it is just for counter, feel free to change it so it will work ;)

Comment: I am getting error. 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' does not contain a definition for 'First' for the line <div class="item (image==item.Images.First()? "active": "")">

Comment: Ok, i've removed it to use a simple boolean

Comment: Thanks it is working. Please remove ; from this line (isFirst = false;). I removed it. then it is working perfectly

Comment: Yes.Sure. Thanks a lot